# PyMC3 hierarchical binomial model - divergences after tuning

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to use pyMC3 to build a simple Bayesian hierarchical model for some experimental data. I have two datasets, but for one of the two the sampler does not converge and I cannot figure out a solution.

The set up is the following:

- There are two experimental conditions (unimaginatively called A and B) and two groups of individuals tested in one of the two conditions (group A and group B).
- Each individual does as many trials as they like, so not all individuals have the same number of trials
- Each trial has a binary outcome (1 or 0).

The data of each subject's performance will be a string of 1s and 0s and I would like to estimate the underlying rate of 1s of each individual from the observed data.

Because for some subjects I have very few trials, I have decided to use a hierarchical Bayesian model (see [this example](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/multilevel_modeling.html)). 
The model I have decided to use is inspired to the one shown [here](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-hierarchical-binominal-model.html) [see code below too].

Now, the model works beautifully for one of the two dataset (B), but the sampler doesn't converge for the other. I have seen online that a possible solution is to switch to a [non centred model](https://twiecki.io/blog/2017/02/08/bayesian-hierchical-non-centered/), but I do not know how to implement that here.

Below is a minimal working example and the results.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




def run():
    # Define data
    datasets_names = ['A', 'B']
    number_of_individuals =[22, 17] # per experimental condition

    # Number of trials and number of successes (1) of each individual
    n_trials_A = [21, 15,  6,  5, 10,  6,  4,  6,  5,  7, 14, 12, 15,  4,  4,  6,  6,  9,  7,  6, 11, 10]
    hits_A = [21, 14,  6,  0,  6,  6,  3,  6,  5,  6, 14,  9, 15,  4,  4,  5,  6,  8,  7,  4,  8, 10]

    n_trials_B = [5,  5, 33,  4, 13, 18, 24,  8,  8,  9,  9,  7, 14,  8, 15,  9, 11]
    hits_B = [2,  5, 26,  3,  7,  7, 13,  6,  1,  5,  4,  2,  7,  5,  9,  4,  1]

    datasets = [(number_of_individuals[0], n_trials_A, hits_A), (number_of_individuals[1], n_trials_B, hits_B)]

    # Model each dataset separately
    for i, (m, n, h) in enumerate(datasets):
        print('Modelling dataset: ', datasets_names[i])

        # pyMC3 model
        with pm.Model() as model:
            # The model is from: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/hierarchical_partial_pooling.html

            # Define hyperpriors
            phi = pm.Uniform('phi', lower=0.0, upper=1.0)

            kappa_log = pm.Exponential('kappa_log', lam=1.5)
            kappa = pm.Deterministic('kappa', tt.exp(kappa_log))

            # define second level of hierarchical model
            thetas = pm.Beta('thetas', alpha=phi*kappa, beta=(1.0-phi)*kappa, shape=m)

            # Likelihood
            y = pm.Binomial('y', n=n, p=thetas, observed=h)

            # Fit
            trace = pm.sample(6000, tune=2000, nuts_kwargs={'target_accept': 0.95}) 

        # Show traceplot
        pm.traceplot(trace)
    plt.show()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This is what gets printed to console when the code runs:

```
Modeeling dataset:  A
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
Multiprocess sampling (4 chains in 4 jobs)
NUTS: [thetas, kappa_log, phi]
Sampling 4 chains: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 32000/32000 [00:52<00:00, 610.30draws/s]
There were 928 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
There were 818 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
There were 885 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
There were 842 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The number of effective samples is smaller than 25% for some parameters.
Modeeling dataset:  B
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
Multiprocess sampling (4 chains in 4 jobs)
NUTS: [thetas, kappa_log, phi]
Sampling 4 chains: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 32000/32000 [00:35<00:00, 899.07draws/s]
```

Accordingly, the traceplots for data set A show that there was no convergence.

[Traceplot for data set A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqGeV.png)

[Traceplot for data set B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KczdO.png)

If anyone can help with tips on how to reparametrize the model that would be great, thank you!